# Ionic 3 modal display message

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic3

I have already designed the Ionic 3 modals. Now I  would like to display some message ( Hello Modal ). How do I display the message inside the modal?
Below is my openModal code.

```
openModal() {
    const myModal = this.modal.create('ModalPage');
    myModal.present();
}
```

I would like to display the message using translate. In my case, the message will be set in en.json file, and from there I need to call the message in the HTML file. This is where I am stuck.

In ionic 1,I have something like ,

```
$translate(['USER_DATA']).then(function(translations) {
                        vm.userData=translations.USER_DATA; 
}
```

And I will be calling `vm.userData` in my HTML which will display the message in modal. how do I achieve the same translate code in ionic 3

Comment: are you using a translation library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core or https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate?

Answer (score 0):

Its that simple.

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
constructor(private translate : TranslateService) 
...
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
```

This is just an overview. Please go-through this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/) to get a better idea.

They have clearly explained where to place en.json file and how to use it.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.translate.get('here your message u want to translate').subscribe(res => {          
     const myModal = this.modal.create('ModalPage',res);
     myModal.present();
})
```

In modalpage get the translated message by 'params.data()' and display as u want